# Filling with Graphics#fillOval looks off

Tags: java, java-2d

I'm attempting to draw a large circle and fill a smaller circle in the center. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 75));

        frame.add(new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawOval(0, 0, 26, 26);
                g2.fillOval(4, 4, 18, 18);
            }

        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The small circle isn't correctly centered and looks weird. However, if I change g2.fillOval(4, 4, 18, 18); to g2.drawOval(4, 4, 18, 18); it looks correctly centered, but obviously not filled. I would expect the two methods to draw the oval at the same position and size. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will have to do with how the antialiasing is working and how your eyes "perceive" it...optical illusion in other words

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there a different rendering option that would work? I don't know all that much about the different rendering options.

Comment: Not really, the issue comes do to the fact that pixels are fractional, you can't have half a pixel for example, so it tries to perform some tricks to apply the softening.  Anything you get to work on you PC probably won't work on some one elses

Comment: This is probably just based on the definition of insideness for shapes - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I call both drawOval AND fillOval, it looks much better, as if drawOval corrected some of the missing pixels.

```
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawOval(0, 0, 26, 26);
            g2.drawOval(4, 4, 18, 18);
            g2.fillOval(4, 4, 18, 18);
```

If I look very closely, some pixels in the southeast area are grey instead of black (as if the drawOval effect was too thin), probably using a stroke with a larger width than the default would correct this as well.